# Javascript toggle function crashes when I swap text for icons

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

EDIT: SIMPLE SWAPING TEXT FOR ICONS WORKS ON CHROME, BUT DOESN'T ON FIREFOX....

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/QWwedJY

Right now it works fine.

However in the menu on top, I'd like to display: instead of Hide have ☑ symbol, and instead of Show have ☐ symbol. Both for Artists and Releases.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar">
    All entries: <a class="glyph" id="showAll">☑</a>
    Artists: <a class="glyph" id="toggleArtists">Hide</a>
    Releases: <a class="glyph" id="toggleReleases">Hide</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.querySelector('#showAll').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = '☑';
    document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').innerHTML = 'Hide';
    document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML = 'Hide';
    document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.style.display = '';
    });
};

document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('li.release').forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.style.display = item.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
    });

    document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').innerHTML == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
    if (document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').innerHTML == 'Hide' && document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide')
        document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = '☑';
    else
        document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = '☐';
};

document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('li.artist').forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.style.display = item.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
    });

    document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
    if (document.querySelector('#toggleReleases').innerHTML == 'Hide' && document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide')
        document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = '☑';
    else
        document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = '☐';
};
```

and if I change all "Hides" to ☑, and all "Shows" to ☐, the toggle function doesn't work...

I'm a JS beginner, please go easy if this is an easy fix?

Is using symbols like that even safe for browsing? If not, what's the best alternative to have those icons and how to implement that?

thank you

Comment: It seems to be working when I replace Hide/Show with your symbols. Please help us on how to reproduce your situation with more details.

Comment: did you replace EVERY single 'Hide' in JS with ☑, and EVERY single 'Show' with ☐? when I do that and reload the website, all the links show ☑ only, and if you try to click it nothing happens

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work on Firefox. could you maybe fork my codepen and post it with your edits please?